# WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException glassfish

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, glassfish

hi I am new to java web programming. Have written two simple jsp pages. one to accept the name, and second to show the entered name. I dont know what and where is wrong with my code. Can any one help me debug the issue. I am attaching my code here

index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Entry Form</h1>
</body><form name="input_form" action="response.jsp">Enter Your Name : <input    type="text" name="name" value="" /><input type="submit" value="Ok" name="submit" />
</form>
</html>
```

response.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body><jsp:useBean id="mybean" scope="session" class="org.mypackage.hello.NameHandler" />
    <jsp:setProperty name="request" property="" /><h1>Hello, <jsp:getProperty name="mybean" property="name" />!</h1>
</body>
```

The exception is thrown on response.jsp page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> two simple jsp pages. one to accept the name, and second to show the entered name.

In `response.jsp` write just

```
${param.name}
```

That will display name from `index.jsp`

Why are you using `<jsp:useBean>` when you are submitting page to `response.jsp`?

Need more information to help you further.

Comment: Thanks for the quick update. But what i am trying to do is just here. I am refering the tutorial.. https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps.html..

Comment: By the way your solution worked for me pretty well.. So do you think the problem was with get and set methods?

Comment: @user3227262 : No. you are submitting form directly to `response.jsp` and you are accessing the property `name` of class `NameHandler`  which is set yet. Please refer [this oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnair.html) or [JSP - JavaBeans](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_java_beans.htm)